# Disconnect from Wi-Fi through Terminal

Tags: bash, macos, command-line, terminal, wifi

I want to create a program that disconnects from WiFi. Note that disconnecting is different from disabling WiFi.

I have looked everywhere for a command to disconnect, but there seems to be none. It is possible to disconnect from WiFi by holding the option key while clicking on the WiFi button.

[image: Disconnect from WiFi Button]

```
sudo networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled Wi-Fi off
```

This code does *NOT* work because it turns off Wi-Fi completely.

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 off
```

This code also does not work because it turns the Wi-Fi off

All help is welcome

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport "XYZ" -z
```

This code simply disconnects from the current WiFi. Replacing `XYZ` with `en0` or `en1` (depending on what shows up on the Interface Name (it was `en0` for me)) will disconnect from the current WiFi.